# Making a choropleth map with folium

Tags: python, choropleth, folium

I have a problem making this choroepth map. The areas are right, i got the numbers correct, but it fills my areas with the same color. My assumption is that I am getting the key_on wrong. My code is based on this tutorial: https://blog.dominodatalab.com/creating-interactive-crime-maps-with-folium/
Code:

```
[district_geo = r'C:/1/sfpddists.geojson' 
SF = (37.783087441092704, -122.46120747577555) 

crimedata2 = pd.DataFrame(df\['Police District'\].value_counts().astype(float)) 
crimedata2.to_json('crimeagg.json') 
crimedata2 = crimedata2.reset_index() 
crimedata2.columns = \['District', 'Number'\] 

m = folium.Map(location=SF, zoom_start=12) 

folium.GeoJson( 
district_geo, 
name='geojson' 
).add_to(m) 


m.choropleth(geo_data=r'C:/1/sfpddists.geojson', data=crimedata2, 
columns=\['District', 'Number'\], 
key_on=None, 
fill_color = 'PuBu', 
fill_opacity = 0.7, 
line_opacity = 0.2, 
highlight=True, 
legend_name = 'Number of incidents per district') 
m][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `key_on` argument expects the name of the field in the GeoJSON data that links to your numerical data. In your code snippet it is set to `None`, so it doesn't work. In the tutorial they use `key_on = 'feature.properties.DISTRICT'`.

This means that in the GeoJSON data each feature will have a property named 'DISTRICT' which I assume will contain the name of a district. Then, in your dataframe you have a column named 'District' with strings that match the value in the GeoJSON 'DISTRICT' field. Where there is a match the value in the 'Number' column will be used to determine the color.